# Get the value of a column where one column is max and another is min

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

From a dataframe like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
            'col1': ['a'] * 20 + ['b'] * 20,
            'col2': (['c'] * 10 + ['d'] * 10)*2,
            'col3': ( ['x'] * 3 + ['y'] * 7)*4,
            'col4': np.random.rand(40),
            'col5': np.random.rand(40),
            }
            )
```

I want to obtain the value of 'col3' where 'col4' is maximum and, if there are two or more rows with the same 'col4' value, choose the one where 'col5' is minimum.

```
dg = df.groupby(('col1', 'col2'), sort=False)['col4'].max()
dh = df.groupby(('col1', 'col2'), sort=False)['col5'].min()
```

So far I have come up with this,

```
dg = df.groupby(('col1', 'col2'), sort=False)\
        .agg({'col4':'max', 'col5':'min'})
```

but it gives me the maximum 'col4' and minimum 'col5' independently, whereas I want the 'col5' value to be the one corresponding to the maximum 'col4' (if there is only one 'col4' maximum row).

Additionally, I would want to have the 'col3' value correspondinig to the max 'col4'. I have this now:

```
df.loc[df.groupby(('col1', 'col2'), sort=False)['col4'].idxmax()]['col3'].reset_index()['col3']
```

which gives me the column I want, but when I put it in the new dataframe, I don't get what I expect, which would be the max 'col4' and min 'col5' and their corresponding 'col3' value:

```
dg['col3'] = df.loc[df.groupby(('col1', 'col2'), sort=False)['col4'].idxmax()]['col3'].reset_index()['col3']
```

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(2020)
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'col1': ['a'] * 10 + ['b'] * 10, 'col2': (['c'] * 5 + ['d'] * 5)*2, 'col3': ( ['x'] * 5 + ['y'] * 5)*2, 'col4': np.random.randint(5, size=20), 'col5': np.random.randint(5, size=20), } )
```

```
   col1 col2 col3  col4  col5
0     a    c    x     0     4
1     a    c    x     0     1
2     a    c    x     3     1
3     a    c    x     3     2
4     a    c    x     3     1
5     a    d    y     3     2
6     a    d    y     0     4
7     a    d    y     0     4
8     a    d    y     0     2
9     a    d    y     0     3
10    b    c    x     2     4
11    b    c    x     1     1
12    b    c    x     3     4
13    b    c    x     3     1
14    b    c    x     2     3
15    b    d    y     3     2
16    b    d    y     0     0
17    b    d    y     4     1
18    b    d    y     4     1
19    b    d    y     0     2
```

The expected output would be:

```
   col1 col2 col3  col4  col5
     a    c    x     3     1
     a    c    x     3     1
     a    d    y     3     2
     b    c    x     3     1
     b    d    y     4     1
     b    d    y     4     1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
np.random.seed(2020)
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'col1': ['a'] * 10 + ['b'] * 10, '
                   col2': (['c'] * 5 + ['d'] * 5)*2, 
                   'col3': ( ['x'] * 5 + ['y'] * 5)*2, 
                   'col4': np.random.randint(5, size=20), 
                   'col5': np.random.randint(5, size=20), } )
print (df)
   col1 col2 col3  col4  col5
0     a    c    x     0     4
1     a    c    x     0     1
2     a    c    x     3     1
3     a    c    x     3     2
4     a    c    x     3     1
5     a    d    y     3     2
6     a    d    y     0     4
7     a    d    y     0     4
8     a    d    y     0     2
9     a    d    y     0     3
10    b    c    x     2     4
11    b    c    x     1     1
12    b    c    x     3     4
13    b    c    x     3     1
14    b    c    x     2     3
15    b    d    y     3     2
16    b    d    y     0     0
17    b    d    y     4     1
18    b    d    y     4     1
19    b    d    y     0     2
```

First are filtered all rows with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) by maximal `col4` by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and comparing with `col4` with [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html)

---

```
df1 = df[df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])['col4'].transform('max').eq(df['col4'])]
print (df1)
   col1 col2 col3  col4  col5
2     a    c    x     3     1
3     a    c    x     3     2
4     a    c    x     3     1
5     a    d    y     3     2
12    b    c    x     3     4
13    b    c    x     3     1
17    b    d    y     4     1
18    b    d    y     4     1

#if need only some columns filter by list
cols = ['col1','col2','col3', 'col4','col5']
mask = df1.groupby(['col1', 'col2'], sort=False)['col5'].transform('min').eq(df1['col5'])
df2 = df1.loc[mask, cols]
print (df2)
   col1 col2 col3  col4  col5
2     a    c    x     3     1
4     a    c    x     3     1
5     a    d    y     3     2
13    b    c    x     3     1
17    b    d    y     4     1
18    b    d    y     4     1
```

Comment: Great, that works almost perfectly. Only I'm not sure if the col5_min is the absolute minimum, or is it the minimum associated to the col4_max and col4_idxmax? How do I check that?

Comment: @acb - Answer was edited, because not count minimal values by rows with maximal `col4`, can you check if correct (what you need) ?

Comment: I'm checking it... the previous answer gave me almost what I needed. Only the check that 'col5' value is minimal from the maximal 'col4' was missing. Now I don't know how to apply the new answer...

Comment: @acb - Unfortunately previous answer not get minimal values from maximal rows, so it was reason why answer was changed.

Comment: Ok, now I understand it, but the thing is in my real dataframe I have many more columns, and I only want these five columns to show, like in the first answer you gave me...

Comment: @acb - Super, thanks, is `b    c    x     3     4` correct in output?

Comment: No, sorry, it's `b c x 3 1`. And now it works like a charm. Thank you!